# Passing arguments to an interactive script which will run in background

Tags: bash

I need to run a program in the background. I know that using '&' after a command runs the command in the background.

In the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo amt of time delay nsec
read nano
echo amt of time delay in sec
read sec
echo no.of times
read i
while [ $i -ne 0 ]
do
./nanosleep $sec $nano
./schello
i=$[i-1]
done
```

I have a few data that I get from the user. Is there a way I can run the program in background and while calling the program can I also specify the data required (like nano, sec,i) as arguments or through some other way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your script is called, let say `test.sh`, then you can for example:

- pipe your input:

  ```
  echo -e "1\n2\n3\n" | test.sh &
  ```

  where `1`, `2`, and `3` are the values for `$nano`, `$sec` and, respectively `$i`.
- take the input from a file:

  ```
  test.sh < arguments.txt &
  ```
- use a here string:

  ```
  test.sh <<< $'1\n2\n3\n' &
  ```

Comment: The 1st one was more than enough though had to use ./test.sh

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to pass those variables as arguments to your script. In your script, instead of

```
read nano
read sec
read i
```

...you may use:

```
nano=$1
sec=$2
i=$3
```

The variables `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc. correspond to the first, second, third, etc. arguments on the command line. Thus you can call your script as:

```
test.sh foo bar buz &
```

Inside the script, `$1` will contain `foo`, `$2` will contain `bar`, `$3` will contain `buz`, etc.